# After install cx_freeze cannot get zip importer

Tags: python, inno-setup, cx-freeze

I use Inno Setup to install a Python application after building with `distutils`.
The output of the build contains the `*.pyd` files in the top level directory, alongside the actual executable.

If I then run this application from the build directory it functions normally.

When I run it after an install, in which the setup script has moved `*.pyd` and `*.dll` into a subdirectory, it seems the application can no longer find these files. I get the following error:

> cx_Freeze Fatal Error
>
> cannot get zipimporter instance

I suspect it is because of moving the required module in the install. Is there any way I can move them into the path? Or tell the application where to look if `frozen` somehow?

I would be satisfied with moving the application executable into the `libs` folder and point a shortcut at it, but this seems sloppy and I really don't prefer it.

To be clear my `build` directory should look familiar.

```
build
  myapp.exe
  _bz2.pyd
  ...
```

After install I purposely end up with something like this.

```
Program Files\MyApp
  myapp.exe
  libs
    _bz2.pyd
    ...
```

Comment: Try using py2exe or pyinstaller to bundle things up for you.

Comment: @steve While it may come to that, I don't feel like I should have to. I do not need a single file executable or anything. I just need to know how to tell it where to look for these.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel  I have had the same problem and ended using Pyinstaller. I recommend Pyinstaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your pyd's, dll's and zips must be in the same folder as the exe at the moment.  This has been on the feature list for cx_freeze, but is not yet implemented.

See this post:
http://sourceforge.net/p/cx-freeze/mailman/message/32075893/